# Trying to split tab delimited list and create list of objects c#

Tags: c#

I have a file upload which receives a tab delimited list that I'm trying to split into a list of employee objects using the headers as properties.  I've tried splitting the list into objects by line as well as by tab, however I'm not getting the correct list of objects.

**Here's an example of the tab separated list:**

domainName  Name    accountname givenname   surname email   physicaldeliveryOffice

"CN=Fred Smith,OU=Sales,OU=MRO,OU=Users,OU=Owasso,OU=Test,DC=test,DC=com"   Fred Smith  Fred.Smith  Fred    Smith   Fred.smith@test.com office"
"CN=John Smith,OU=Sales,OU=MRO,OU=Users,OU=Miramar,OU=test,DC=test,DC=com"  John Smith  John.Smith  John    Smith   John.smith@test.com office"

**What I'd like is to create a list of employees using the columns as properties..**

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

Employee Class

```
 public class Employee
{
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName { get; set; }
}
```

Code that reads and parses the list into objects:

```
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/" + fileName));
            string[] delimitedByLine = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.FullName).Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var employeesList = delimitedByLine.Select(x => new Employee
            {
                DomainName = x[0].ToString(),
                Name = x[1].ToString(),
                AccountName = x[2].ToString(),
                GivenName = x[3].ToString(),
                Surname = x[4].ToString(),
                Email = x[5].ToString(),
                PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName = x[6].ToString()


            }).ToList();

            return employeesList;
```

**Update**

After some help, here's what I was able to do to get it to work:

```
public ActionResult Parse(string fileName)

    {
        try

        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/" + fileName));
            string[] delimitedByLine = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.FullName).Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

            var employeeList = delimitedByLine.Select(x =>
            {
                string[] delimitedByTab = x.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                return new Employee()
                {
                    DomainName = delimitedByTab[0].Replace("\"", ""),
                    Name = delimitedByTab[1],
                    SamAccountName = delimitedByTab[2],
                    GivenName = delimitedByTab[3],
                    Surname =  delimitedByTab[4],
                    Email = delimitedByTab[5],
                    PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName = delimitedByTab[6]
                };
            }).ToList();
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Employees", employeeList);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Comment: there are ldap string parsers...

Comment: @DanielA.White I was ultimately not trying to add any dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the string in each line.

```
var employeeList = delimitedByLine.Select(x=>
{
    string[] delimitedByComma = x.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return new Employee()
    {
       DomainName = delimitedByComma[0],
       Name = delimitedByComma[1],
       AccountName = delimitedByComma[2],
       GivenName = delimitedByComma[3],
       Surname = delimitedByComma[4],
       Email = delimitedByComma[5],
       PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName = delimitedByComma[6]
    }
}).ToList();;
```